# Rewrite equation as polynomial

Tags: python, sympy

```
from sympy import *
K, T, s = symbols('K T s')
G = K/(1+s*T)
Eq1 =Eq(G+1,0)
```

I want to rewrite equation `Eq1` with sympy as polynomial: 1+K+T*s==0

How would I do this?

I spent some hours of searching and trying simplifications methods but could not find a elegant, short solution.

The actual problem in SymPy:

```
from IPython.display import display 
import sympy as sp
sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True,use_latex=True,euler=True)
Kf,Td0s,Ke,Te,Tv,Kv,s= sp.symbols("K_f,T_d0^',K_e,T_e,T_v,K_v,s")
Ga= Kf/(1+s*Tv)
Gb= Ke/(1+s*Te)
Gc= Kf/(1+s*Td0s)
G0=Ga*Gb*Gc
G1=sp.Eq(G0+1,0)
display(G1)
```

How to tell Sympy to rewrite equation G1 as polynomial in shape s^3*(...)+s^2*(...)+s*(...)+(...)=...               ?

The actual problem from textbook: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vyiEx.png

How it should look like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iobNU.png

The two equations are equivalent.

Comment: I do not fully get the intention i.e. the meaning of "rewriting the equation". Why do you don't define a new equation "Eq2 = Eq(N+1,0)" with "N = K + T*s"?

Comment: Sorry, I forget to mention this is a minimal example. My actual problem consists of several transfer function G1, G2, G3... of the type K/(1+s*T). The resulting equation is G1*G2*G3+1==0 and this I would like to have in polynomial form.

Comment: Still do not get it but might be the heat ;) Could you edit the question and explain it for the G1*G2*G3+1==0 case? This would at least help me to think about a solution...

Comment: Thank you for your replies. I updated to show the actual problem, does this help? Thanks and regards.

Comment: Still don't get it. :( What is wrong with the current output and how is it supposed to look like? Maybe you can replace your s^3*()... in your question by the actual desired output to show exactly what you want to obtain?!

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://docs.sympy.org/dev/tutorial/basic_operations.html#substitution

Comment: Just do `Eq1.subs(G, K/(1+s*T)`

Comment: Hi Cleb, thank you for caring so much. I uploaded two scans from the textbook where the equations are from. Does this help? Regards Malte

Comment: To start of you can try this (G0 + 1).as_numer_denom(). This function will return a tuple containing (numerator, denominator). @Malte

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's what you can do.

```
import sympy as sp
Kf,Td0s,Ke,Te,Tv,Kv,s= sp.symbols("K_f,T_d0^',K_e,T_e,T_v,K_v,s")
Ga= Kf/(1+s*Tv)
Gb= Ke/(1+s*Te)
Gc= Kf/(1+s*Td0s)
G0=Ga*Gb*Gc
```

Throw away the denominator

```
eq = (G0 + 1).as_numer_denom()[0]
```

Expand the equation and collect terms with powers of s.

```
eq = eq.expand().collect(s)
```

Final Equation

```
Eq(eq, 0)
Eq(K_e*K_f**2 + T_d0^'*T_e*T_v*s**3 + s**2*(T_d0^'*T_e + T_d0^'*T_v + T_e*T_v) + s*(T_d0^' + T_e + T_v) + 1, 0)
```

Comment: Hi Sartaj Singh, thanks. That is solving my problem. Initially I was looking for a one-step solution but I am fine with your approach. Especially the possibilities of eq.expand().collect(s) I did not knew. Thanks to all all helpers here.

Comment: Glad that helped. Documentation for most of such functions can be found here http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/simplify/simplify.html.