# Re-writing sympy expression as cubic polynomial with defined variables and coefficients

Tags: python-3.x, math, sympy

Given an expression in sympy, how do I re-write the expression as a polynomial defined as [1]:

```
D11*(omega**2/k**2)**3 + D22*(omega**2/k**2)**2 + D33*(omega**2/k**2) + D44 = 0
```

Note that this is different from the similar question asked here ([Rewrite equation as polynomial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31207395/rewrite-equation-as-polynomial)).
Let

```
x=(omega**2/k**2)
```

then

```
D11*x**3 + D22*x**2 + D33*x + D44 = 0
```

I would like to find `D11`, `D22`, `D33`, and `D44`, given that `x=omega**2/k**2`

Normally, the collect function (http://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/simplification.html) would collect similar terms, but in this situation, it does not seem to work well.

Here is a simple example that helps to explain what I am trying to accomplish.  The output should be in the form `D11*(omega**2/k**2)**3 + D22*(omega**2/k**2)**2 + D33*(omega**2/k**2) + D44 = 0`

```
from sympy import symbols, collect
from IPython.display import display
omega = symbols('omega')
k = symbols('k')
a = symbols('a')
b = symbols('b')
c = symbols('c')
D11 = a*b*c
D22 = c+b
D33 = a+c*b + b
D44 = a+b
x = omega**2/k**2
expr = (D11*x**3 + D22*x**2 + D33*x + D44)
expr0 = expr.expand()
expr1 = collect(expr0, x)
display(expr1)
```

The output is:

```
a*b*c*omega**6/k**6 + a + b + omega**2*(a + b*c + b)/k**2 + omega**4*(b + c)/k**4
```

Although numerically correct, I would like the polynomial in the form [1] given above, and once it is in the form, I would like to extract the `D11`, `D22`, `D33`, and `D44` coefficients.

Using `evaluate=False` in the `collect` function gets me closer to the goal, since the output now becomes:

`{omega**2/k**2: a + b*c + b, omega**4/k**4: b + c, omega**6/k**6: a*b*c, 1: a + b}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with your expr1,

```
expr1 = a*b*c*omega**6/k**6 + a + b + omega**2*(a + b*c + b)/k**2 + omega**4*(b + c)/k**4
```

it seems the easiest way to get the coefficients is to turn x into a symbol, at least temporarily:

```
Poly(expr1.subs(x, Symbol('x')), Symbol('x')).all_coeffs()
```

returns `[a*b*c, b + c, a + b*c + b, a + b]` (the coefficients are listed starting with the highest degree).

I would probably have `x = Symbol('x')` there to begin with, and only use `expr.subs(x, omega**2/k**2)` when needed.

---

SymPy's internal order of terms in a sum cannot be changed. To "rearrange" a SymPy expression means to *print* it in a more human-friendly form. This is largely a string manipulation problem, as we are no longer producing a SymPy object.

```
str(Poly(expr1.subs(x, Symbol('x')), Symbol('x'))).replace('x', '(' + str(x) + ')')
```

returns `Poly(a*b*c*(omega**2/k**2)**3 + (b + c)*(omega**2/k**2)**2 + (a + b*c + b)*(omega**2/k**2) + a + b, (omega**2/k**2), domain='ZZ[a,b,c]')`

Adding `.split(',')[0].replace('Poly(', '')` to the above removes the meta-data of a polynomial, leaving `a*b*c*(omega**2/k**2)**3 + (b + c)*(omega**2/k**2)**2 + (a + b*c + b)*(omega**2/k**2) + a + b`

Comment: Great - that sounds good, what about also re-writing the expression in the form [1] as shown above.

Comment: Could you clarify what is meant by "only use `expr.subs(x, omega**2/k**2)` when needed"

Comment: I mean that having an expression with symbol `x` is better than having it with `omega**2/k**2`. The former can be easily turned into later whenever desired, using `subs`. Going back is more complicated.